# pygame.transform.chop not working

Tags: python, image, save, pygame, crop

I am trying to make a program that loads and image and then splits it in different parts and saves these differenct parts in a folder. However, instead of saving the cropped image it saves the whole image

```
 import sys, pygame
 from pygame import *
 pygame.init()
 while True:
     image=pygame.image.load(raw_input("Enter the file: "))
     rows=int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
     columns=int(input("Enter the number of columns: "))
     output=raw_input("Enter the output folder: ")
     width=image.get_width()/columns
     height=image.get_height()/rows
     print ("In progress...")
     for i in range(0, rows):
         for j in range(0, columns):
             cropped_image=pygame.transform.chop(image, (j*columns, i*rows, width, height))
             cropped_output=output+"/" + str(i)+"_"+str(j)+".png"
             pygame.image.save(cropped_image, cropped_output)
     print ("completed")
```

instead of saving cropped_image (only a part of the image) it saves the whole image. Any idea why it dosen't work?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are chopping into tiles of size `width` x `height`. So the origin of the tile on row `i` and column `j` is `j*width`, `i*height` - not `j*columns`, `i*rows`.

Comment: Made that exact same mistake more than once myself ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using pygame.transform.chop I would suggest you try using [Surface.subsurface](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.subsurface) with the rect that you're specifying. In the Pygame documentation for pygame.transform.chop it states -

> If you want a "crop" that returns the part of an image within a rect, you can blit with a rect to a new surface or copy a subsurface.

So for your example it would be:

```
cropped_image=image.subsurface((j*columns, i*rows, width, height))
```

Comment: It crops the images but it dosent cropped them as it should, they are not in order and the are cropped at the wrong place

Comment: You will need to tweak your rect code to give you the crops you want, I didn't test that as I dont have your source image. The subsurface method is the way to perform a crop